# Reference result from Excel Filter function to be used in drop-down

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I use the `Filter` function in Excel and successfully get a resulting list of values:

[image]

Now I want to reference that list to be used as the content of a `drop down` list - something like this:
[image]

As the resulting list is dynamic and will change in length from time to time, I don't want to make a hard reference to lots of cells, I only want to reference the actual result and nothing else.

I think I saw somewhere that you should use a special character or something to reference the list, but I can't find any information about how to do that when searching for it.

Comment: You want to use Dynamic Named Range instead of selecting data range to filter  through Drop Down or what , please [edit] your post & be specific about your need, also add some sample data along with expected output .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using **#**

First we filter column **A** to only display only items appearing one time and put the filter results in column **B**, SPILLing down from **B1**:

[image]

Next we insert DV into **C1** referencing this SPILL-down using the very simple:

```
=B1#
```

[image]

The result is dynamic as well:

[image]

**NOTES:**

The **#** notation can be used in a cell as well as the DV Dialog.  Just pick a cell and enter:

```
=B1#
```

to dynamically replicate **B1**'s SPILL-down structure.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Hash was the character I was looking for. I probably read 50 sites regarding the filter function without coming across the info regarding hash sign - do you remember where you learned about it? It would be interesting to look at that page if a web page was where you learned about this originally.

Comment: @nivis  I agree with you!! This SPILL-down stuff is really cool.  .................I will look for reference material online and amend this answer as I find it.........